# Mongoose aggregate merge data in one collection after lookup to one object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a collection A with data like

```
{
 id: 2,
 name: "test"
},
{
 id: 4,
 name: "test4"
}
```

and I have a second collection B with data like:

```
{
 id: 444,
 name: "a",
 colA_id: 2
},
{
 id: 555,
 name: "b",
 colA_id: 2
},
{
 id: 555,
 name: "c",
 colA_id: 10
},
```

After I aggregate both collections, I want an output like:

```
{
 id: 2,
 name: "test",
 list_of_b: {
   {
     id: 444,
     name: "a",
     colA_id: 2
   },
   {
    id: 555,
    name: "b",
    colA_id: 2
   },
  }
}
```

I tried to merge them, but every time I only get one record of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a simple look up

The DB is

```
db={
  "collA": [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "test"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "test4"
    }
  ],
  "collB": [
    {
      id: 444,
      name: "a",
      colA_id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 555,
      name: "b",
      colA_id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 555,
      name: "c",
      colA_id: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

And the aggregation is

```
db.collA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collB",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "colA_id",
      "as": "list_of_b"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UpyNGVUXhX9)**

Comment: Hey. Thanks! without unwind and afterwards match and project, it's working on my side either. But somehow after the other steps it only shows one record.

Comment: Ohhh! I just deleted unwind and it worked. My bad. Thanks!!